# Selenium database test fails when executed using ant script

Tags: java, sql, selenium, ant, webdriver

I have a selenium webdriver test which connects to a database, executes a query and stores the values in a string. Then I do stuff with that.

This test works fine when I execute test in Twist (based on Eclipse).

But when I execute test using an ant script, it fails stating **null pointer exception, also seeing this.. [twist.runner] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQ
LServerDriver**.

**The Code Snippets:**

```
public void verifyUserCreatedInTslUserProfileAndSubscriptionTables() throws Exception {

    String userDetails = Products.verifyUserDetailsInSubscriptionTable(); 

    verifyTrue("User details in subscription table did not match, please check manually", userDetails.contentEquals("1215401"));
}


public static String verifyUserDetailsInSubscriptionTable() throws IOException, SQLException {

    String userSubscriptionDetails = null;

    DBAccess.getConnection(ConnectionStrings.databaseConnect("authentication"), ConnectionStrings.getLoginDetailsDB("username"), ConnectionStrings.getLoginDetailsDB("password"));  

    Statement stmt = DBAccess.con.createStatement();    
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(ConnectionStrings.getSqlQuery("verifySubscription"));

    while (result.next()) { userSubscriptionDetails = result.getString("ServiceID")+result.getString("Status")+result.getString("AutoRenew"); }

    DBAccess.closeConnection();
    return userSubscriptionDetails;
}


public class DBAccess {

 public static java.sql.Connection  con = null;

 public static java.sql.Connection getConnection(String conurl, String userName, String password) {

     try {

         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
         con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(conurl,userName,password);         
         if (con != null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");       
     }
     catch(Exception e){

           e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + e.getMessage());
     }

      return con;
  }


public static String databaseConnect(String connection) throws IOException {

    String conurl = null; 
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";

    switch (connection) {                       

    case "authentication": 
        if (Configuration.getSqlServerName().contains("stage")) { conurl = url + "tslauthentication.database.ST.tslweb.local"; break; } 
        else if (!Configuration.getSqlServerName().contains("stage")) { conurl = url + Configuration.getSqlServerName(); break; }
        else break;

    case "tes_connect":
        conurl = url
        +Configuration.getSqlServerName() + ".tslwebdev.local"+":"
        +1433+";databaseName="
        +"tes_connect"+";selectMethod="
        +"cursor"+";"; break;

    }

    connection = conurl;
    return connection; 
}
```

**Error returned by Ant:**

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.products.NewUserSubscribes.verifyUserCreatedInTslUserProfileAndSubscriptionTables(NewUserSubscribes.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

Comment: which line is line 68

Comment: is that full stack trace?

Comment: sorry, line 68 is:   String userDetails = Products.verifyUserDetailsInSubscriptionTable();

Comment: got a bit more info from stack trace... [twist.runner] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQ
LServerDriver

Comment: I dont really love it, but start using maven - ant is hell

Comment: The error says it all: "ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQ LServerDriver" You are missing a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

really silly thing. managed to fix it by adding the jdbc driver to the classpath.